# NES11 touchscreen not working (getting Firmware Request error)

Tags: touchscreen

This is my first install and use of Ubuntu, so I don't know much about linux.

I installed Ubuntu on a NuVision NES11 and the touchscreen doesnt work.

I am getting an error at bootup
[6.598563] silead_ts 12c-MSSL1680:00 Firmware request error -2
[10.295038] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22

I found a few files people made to help fix the issues but i dont know what to do with them the first one is this Bug fix i found ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1862498 ) and this ( https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2411590 ) but it looks to be mostly people saying they have the same issue. Lastly I found a github that made new silead_ts.fw files but i cant seem to find how to install them.  any help would be awesome.

EDIT: Ive got the touchscreen to stop giving me the error -2 at boot up,(Found the info on Hackaday)  It now works kind of.... only in about a 2in by 2in square in the in the middle of the screen.  It looks like the patch file i found will fix the calibration but I dont know how to install it.